# Is there an alternative to UUIDs / GUIDs that doesn't cause database performance issues?

Tags: uuid, guid

As described [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid), using a UUID / GUID is a bad idea in a relational database context. Is there an alternative that has library support?

Comment: "This blog is mostly eliminated in MySQL 8.0" - directly from that link.

Comment: @mxmissile Yes, but it illustrates the issue well, and maybe I'm not using MySQL 8. Even if I was, I still need to be careful about how I store UUIDs and use the correct functions. I expect many application designers will forget to do so and use varchar(36)...

Answer (score 2):

Not a great blog post. GUIDs are great in a situation where a client needs to generate its own primary key. If it's ok that the server generate the key, use an auto-incrementing integer primary key.

Let me elaborate on why this is not a great blog post. He says:

> GUIDs/UUIDs are very random. Therefore, INSERTing into an index means jumping around a lot.

a Guid is really just a 16 Byte hex number; so I could come up with a naive index where a single insert could be done in constant time by just making a 32/16 array that you could traverse through digit by digit. So, inserting N items with my naive index could be done in Log(N) time. The argument in the blog post is terrible. I'm not sure have fast a GUID insert is but the "randomness" has nothing to do with the algorithmic complexity.

Here's a good blog post with some good links:

https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/

I particularly like this link:

http://web.archive.org/web/20150511162734/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-should-i-choose-for-my-primary-key.html

Good discussion of the tradeoffs of different keys.

Comment: I expect to use this format for all entities stored in the enterprise, which could be 100's of billions of rows, each with multiple versions. So yes, performance matters, otherwise the UUID format would be fine. I want multiple server processes to generate ids that never clash across the entire range.